# recarray with lists: how to reference first element in list

Tags: numpy, recarray

I want to copy contents of a few fields in a record array into a ndarray (both type float64).
I know how to do this when the recarray data has a single value in each field:

```
my_ndarray[:,0]=my_recarray['X']  #(for field 'X')
```

Now I have a recarray with a list of 5 floats in each field, and I only want to 
copy the first element of each list.
When I use the above with the new recarray (and list), I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (92,5) into shape (92)
```

That makes total sense (in hindsight).

I thought I could get just the first element of each with this:

```
my_ndarray[:,0]=my_recarray['X'][0]  #(for field 'X')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (92)
```

I sorta understand...numpy is only taking the first row (5 elements) and trying to broadcast into a 92 element column.

So....now I'm wondering how to get the first element of each list down the 92 element column,
Scratchin my head....
Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: I don't work with recarray, really, but... Have you try `my_ndarray[:,0]=my_recarray['X',0]`? just a thought

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. I added a couple of print statments to sniff around:
`print (stress_array[0]['XR'][0]) # gets first row, first list element
print (stress_array[0]['XR'][1]) # gets first row, second list element
print (stress_array[1]['XR'][0]) # gets second row, first list element
print (stress_array[1]['XR'][1]) # gets second row, second list element`
And so on...

Comment: Give us a small example, so we can sure we are working with the same kind of array as you are.  More than likely an answer will include working demonstration code.  Save us the trouble of making up the demonstration example.

Comment: I inherited this dataset from an upstream process. It's a complicated recarray. I'll see if I can create a simple example to demonstrate behavior. In the interim, I figured out a brute force loop does the job:
`for r_cnt in range(stress_array.shape[0]) :
    resvec_array[r_cnt, 0]=stress_array[r_cnt]['XR'][0]`
So, I have a solution. Not sure if it's "the best solution" but I can move forward. Unfortunately, I have to do this for 12 fields. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `recarray` has a `dtype` where one of the fields has shape 5:

```
In [48]: dt = np.dtype([('X',int,5),('Y',float)])
In [49]: arr = np.zeros(3, dtype=dt)
In [50]: arr
Out[50]: 
array([([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0.),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0.)], dtype=[('X', '<i8', (5,)), ('Y', '<f8')])
```

Accessing this field by name produces an array that is (3,5) shape (analogous to your (92,5):

```
In [51]: arr['X']
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This could be described as a list of 5 items for each record, but indexing with field name produces a 2d array, which can be indexing like any 2d numpy array.

Let's set those values to something interesting:

```
In [52]: arr['X'] = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
In [53]: arr
Out[53]: 
array([([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4], 0.), ([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9], 0.),
       ([10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 0.)],
      dtype=[('X', '<i8', (5,)), ('Y', '<f8')])
```

We can fetch the first column of this field with:

```
In [54]: arr['X'][:,0]
Out[54]: array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

If you have several fields with a structure like this, you'll probably have to access each one by name.  There's a limit to what you can do with multi-field indexing.

Comment: Excellent!! You are exactly right (In fact there are at least 12 fields with dtype shape 5). My initial tests work as expect. Thank you, thank you. 
Obviously I'm new at this. How do folks get the pretty code formatting in their posts with In [##]: and Out[##]:

Comment: The `In/Out` numbering is produced by `ipython`.  It's a very good interactive Python environment.